# Ef 6 RemoveRange in Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

```
IQueryable<PortServicesTariffDetail> detalis = _context.PortServicesTariffDetails
                                   .Where(w => w.PortServicesTariffId == TariffId &&
                                          w.PortServicesTariffDetailId == DetailId);
if (detalis.Count() > 0)
{
 var mydetial = detalis.GroupBy(g => new { g.StartRate,g.EndRate }).AsQueryable();
 _context.PortServicesTariffDetails.RemoveRange(mydetial.AsQueryable());
 _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Depends on the start and end rate remove range, I have raise some issue like anonymous type. so what can I do???

> Argument 1: cannot convert from  'System.Linq.IQueryable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Comment: Could you paste the exception? So it will be easier to identify correctly the problem?

Comment: Error 43 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,Alpine_Dev.Models.PortServicesTariffDetail>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Alpine_Dev.Models.PortServicesTariffDetail>'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach(var x in mydetial)
{
  _context.PortServicesTariffDetails.RemoveRange(x.ToList());
}

 _context.SaveChanges();
```

But I don't understand why you're grouping everything to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var detalis = _context.PortServicesTariffDetails
                                   .Where(w => w.PortServicesTariffId == TariffId &&
                                          w.PortServicesTariffDetailId == DetailId).ToList();

if (detalis.Count() > 0)
{
 var mydetial = detalis.GroupBy(g => new { g.StartRate,g.EndRate }).AsQueryable();
 _context.PortServicesTariffDetails.RemoveRange(mydetial.AsQueryable());
 _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I think there is no need to use Group by,
You can simply use `RemoveRange`

```
_context.PortServicesTariffDetails.RemoveRange(detalis);
 _context.SaveChanges();
```